# Prove that OLS estimator of AR(1) coefficient for an AR(p) process with unit root converges to 1

Tags: time-series, unit-root

Suppose that the DGP is an AR(p) with a unit root. When we fit, using OLS, an AR(1) model $x_t=\alpha x_{t-1}+u_t$ to the data, we get $\alpha=1$, indicating, correctly, that this is a unit root process. I've been trying to prove this, but so far I've not been successful. Can someone give some hints?

Comment: See e.g. [17.6.6] in Hamilton, Time Series Analysis, which implies (under in fact more general nonparametric assumptions on the serial correlation in $x_t$) that $T(\hat\alpha-1)=O_p(1)$, which implies that $\hat\alpha\to_p1$.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks, this is exactly what I needed. Hamilton is a great source for more serious and rigorous information on time series. Do you happen to have any recommendation for other books on time series that are as good?

Comment: I agree that Hamilton is as good as it gets (see Pötschers review in Journal of the American Statistical Association 91, 1996, 439-440, https://www.jstor.org/stable/2291435, though...) for detailed derivations of key results. The books by Brockwell/Davis, Hannan/Deistler, Fuller, Tanaka and many others are impressive too, though!

Comment: @ChristophHanck Don't have access unfortunately, does the review identify some problems with the book?

Comment: @ChristophHanck Thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look

Comment: Yes indeed, it mentions some mistakes. Feel free to PM for a pdf.